# Extracting names and values from a line using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I want to extract names and variables from a line and then store them in a dictionary as a key value  pair using regular expression in python.
Eg:

```
A has 50000 rupees and B has 15000 rupees.C has 7854 rupees and D has 10000 rupees
```

It should look like `{'A':50000,'B':15000,'C':7854,'D':10000}`. Also integer can not have more than 5 digits

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern: `([a-zA-Z])(?=\shas\s(\d{,5}))`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/buRRSV/1)

Code:

```
import re

pattern = r'([a-zA-Z])(?=\shas\s(\d{,5}))'
text = 'A has 50000 rupees and B has 15000 rupees.C has 7854 rupees and D has 10000 rupees'
kv = {}
for key, value in re.findall(pattern, text):
    kv[key] = value

print(kv)
```

Output:

```
{'A': '50000', 'B': '15000', 'C': '7854', 'D': '10000'}
```